# How bootstrap functionality works using data attribute only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know how bootstrap functionalities work with the use of data attribute even without using javascript to trigger it.

An simple example of this is the [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). Notice on the scripts provided, the tooltip functionality works by just using `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Alternatively, you may also trigger it via javascript.

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

I would like to make some sort of the same functionality where I can just assign `data-myplugin="toggle"` and it will trigger the toggle functionality.

Answer (score 0):

because the data attribute already contain a CSS selector that points to the HTML Element that will be changed. And it used by bootstrap to make your life easier. Plus you don't need to write a single line of Javascript to use their pre-made [JavaScript components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript).

Further information about the HTML5 "data-" attribute: 
[Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)